# redirect from @ActionMapping w/o invoking the pointless @RenderMapping

Tags: java, liferay

How to redirect from @ActionMapping handler method and avoid the subsequent automatic/default @RenderMapping call?

**Why I (think I) need this**

I have @ActionMapping method which "does stuff" and then redirects to @RenderMapping method **in the same controller**. I want to perform the redirect between these two *sibling* methods to prevent the @ActionMapping handler getting called (and doing stuff) in case user refreshed the page. Should user do so only the @RenderMapping handler gets called this time.

Currently when I click the link pointing to my @ActionMapping handler the @RenderMapping handler gets called twice. Once as a default follow-up after the @ActionMapping and once as a result of the successful redirect.

Comment: This is the default behavior of Liferay. Once the call to action method gets completed, it automatically calls render method to refresh the contents of the portlet.

Comment: I am able to understand your first point, in which you want to restrict re-calling of action method on refreshing the page. It happens because URL contains reference to the previously called action.

Comment: @ParkashKumar yes, i wonder is there a way of preventing that behavior (some flag maybe)

Comment: It sortof/almost works now, when i hit refresh the ActionMapping does not get called, but the first navigation invokes the RenderMapping twice

Answer (score 1):

> I had somewhat similar problem of portlet's action being called on
>   refreshing the page (unintentional), once I had previously invoked
>   action using button or link (intentional).

**Workaround:**

I had Placed a hidden field on the `view` and populated it with current URL excluding `queryString` using javascript (getting called on clicking button or link) as following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" id="redirect" value="" />

function setRedirectURL() {
    document.getElementById('redirect').value = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
}
```

And then retrieved that `request` parameter in action method and manually redirected to it's value on successful completion of action, as:

```
String redirect = actionRequest.getParameter("redirect");

if (redirect != null && redirect != "") {
    actionResponse.sendRedirect(redirect);
}
```

Which resulted in flushing the `queryString` parameters. So, next time URL becomes plain and even on refreshing page will just invoke portlet's render method.

Comment: @Jaroslav Záruba, Is this, something you want?